# Internet Connectivity Check in every second in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, internet-connection

I need  to check internet connectivity in every second on my app.I got many way to do this task after little search in google.Guys please give the suggestion  which is the best way to check internet connectivity in an app.

Comment: Don't.  There is no method to check every second which doesn't drain the battery for absolutely no reason at all.  You may also unnecessarily use data from the user's limited data plan.

Comment: Otherwise how i can get my device is connected or not with internet in a particular time???

Comment: Why do you need to know?  If not, you get feedback when you try an operation that requires such a connection.

Comment: Always use Apples reachability class

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking whether the network is reachable yourself every `n` seconds, the better way is to observe changes to reachability.

You can do this directly with the Apple APIs (see [the Reachability sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_9) on the Apple dev site), but it would be much easier to use the Reachability functionality built into whatever network library you're using.

Try:

- [`Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#user-content-network-reachability) for Swift
- [`AFNetworkReachabilityManager`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#user-content-network-reachability-manager) in AFNetworking for Objective-C

Comment: Unless one is already using AFNetworking, the sample code available from Apple is simple to use and doesn't add unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Use AFNetworkReachabilityManager in AFNetworking:

AFNetworking Reachability does check continuously the network connection

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];

}

//Use the return value to check the Internet connection
-(BOOL)connected {

    return [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];

-(BOOL)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)note
{
    BOOL status =YES;
    NSLog(@"reachability is changed");

    Reachability * reach = [note object];

    if([reach isReachable])
    {
        status = YES;
        NSLog(@"NetWork is Available. Please go ahead");
    }
    else
    {
        status = NO;
        NSLog(@"NetWork is not Available. Please check your connection.");
    }
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download reachability classes, those will be enough

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/756wihhgu1cbq34/AACAeg-pzmXf-k1oWA7-rGYLa?dl=0

Comment: I got it in apple doc ..:) anyway thanks

Comment: Welcome, Happy coding..